# Python Selenium как вставить не текст а картинку из буфера обмена find_element_by_xpath("*").send_keys(u"текст 1").send_keys(картинка)

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, изображения, selenium

Python Selenium как вставить не текст а картинку из буфера обмена?

Использовать какую-ту другую команду, чем send_keys()?

```
find_element_by_xpath("*").send_keys(u"текст 1").send_keys(img_kart)
```

img - картинка

```
import requests
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import win32clipboard

response = requests.get(url="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/20/Emergency_hospital_during_Influenza_epidemic%2C_Camp_Funston%2C_Kansas_-_NCP_1603.jpg/220px-Emergency_hospital_during_Influenza_epidemic%2C_Camp_Funston%2C_Kansas_-_NCP_1603.jpg")
image = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content)) # convert it to a "Image" Object
tempIO = BytesIO() 
image.save(tempIO,'PNG') # save it to a IO object as BMP format

# write it to clipboard
win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
img_kart = win32clipboard.SetClipboardData(win32clipboard.CF_DIB,tempIO.getvalue()[14:])


find_element_by_xpath("*").send_keys(u"текст 1").send_keys(картинка)
```

`find_element_by_xpath("*")` -  это обьект, где можно вставлять текст и картинки из буфера и редактировать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

html код фрагмента для вставки и обработки текста

```
<div class="_13Sj3UMDKkCCJTq88berCB "><div><div class="DraftEditor-root"><div class="DraftEditor-editorContainer"><div class="notranslate public-DraftEditor-content" role="textbox" spellcheck="true" style="outline:none;user-select:text;-webkit-user-select:text;white-space:pre-wrap;word-wrap:break-word" contenteditable="true"><div data-contents="true"><div data-offset-key="000ee8_initial-0-0" class="_3LuG0YVLLHE2azRNVaKz7O"><div class="" data-block="true" data-editor="000ee8" data-offset-key="000ee8_initial-0-0"><div data-offset-key="000ee8_initial-0-0" class="public-DraftStyleDefault-block public-DraftStyleDefault-ltr"><span data-offset-key="000ee8_initial-0-0"><span data-text="true">текст 1</span></span></div></div><div class="" data-block="true" data-editor="000ee8" data-offset-key="c2eq8-0-0"><div data-offset-key="c2eq8-0-0" class="public-DraftStyleDefault-block public-DraftStyleDefault-ltr"><span data-offset-key="c2eq8-0-0"><span data-text="true">тут изображение 1</span></span></div></div><div class="" data-block="true" data-editor="000ee8" data-offset-key="4rgik-0-0"><div data-offset-key="4rgik-0-0" class="public-DraftStyleDefault-block public-DraftStyleDefault-ltr"><span data-offset-key="4rgik-0-0"><span data-text="true">текст 2</span></span></div></div><div class="" data-block="true" data-editor="000ee8" data-offset-key="9jjlu-0-0"><div data-offset-key="9jjlu-0-0" class="public-DraftStyleDefault-block public-DraftStyleDefault-ltr"><span data-offset-key="9jjlu-0-0"><span data-text="true">тут изображение 2</span></span></div></div><div class="" data-block="true" data-editor="000ee8" data-offset-key="c1fq7-0-0"><div data-offset-key="c1fq7-0-0" class="public-DraftStyleDefault-block public-DraftStyleDefault-ltr"><span data-offset-key="c1fq7-0-0"><br data-text="true"></span></div></div><div class="" data-block="true" data-editor="000ee8" data-offset-key="c7smd-0-0"><div data-offset-key="c7smd-0-0" class="public-DraftStyleDefault-block public-DraftStyleDefault-ltr"><span data-offset-key="c7smd-0-0"><br data-text="true"></span></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="tVQ1dB4n0mAWdcQNxFq-K _1z9S1KmnM79xn-UA0FnbP6 "></div></div>
```

Может можно как-то сделать через Robot Framework?

Comment: А куда надо вставить? HTML отрывок можно

Answer (score 1):

Используйте Robot Framework Test Automation или в документации к selenium видела что есть такая опция

http://python4u.blogspot.com/2012/07/robot-framework.html
https://habr.com/ru/company/maxilect/blog/470924/

в Youtube тоже есть примеры как с ним работать